# Avoid Exception when there is no data

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, package, procedure

I am working on a project and I have a database schema written in Oracle DB. I have some issues.

I'll show you my existing code ->

```
PACKAGE BODY pkg_customer_overview
IS
 PROCEDURE get_invest_agreement_info (
    opassport_no    OUT VARCHAR2,
    onational_id_no OUT VARCHAR2,
  BEGIN
  SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN doc_type=2 THEN doc_number ELSE '' END),
         MAX(CASE WHEN doc_type=1 THEN doc_number ELSE '' END)
         INTO opassport_no,
              onational_id_no
  FROM cusmm_cus_document
  WHERE customer_number=c.customer_number
  GROUP BY customer_number;
```

Now I want to make sure to run sp even if cusmm_cus_document table is empty.

[image: cusmm_cus_document]

Comment: You can handle exception NO_DATA_FOUND. For example, `BEGIN ... YOUR_CODE... EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN NULL; END;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `GROUP BY`.  An aggregation query with no `GROUP BY` always returns exactly one row.  The columns will be `NULL`:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN doc_type = 2 THEN doc_number END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN doc_type = 1 THEN doc_number END)
INTO opassport_no, onational_id_no
FROM cusmm_cus_document c
WHERE c.customer_number = in_customer_number;
```

Notes:

- `customer_number` appears to be a parameter but it conflicts with the column name.  Give it a different name!
- I removed the `ELSE ''` in the `CASE` expressions.  `''` is `NULL` anyway, and the default returned value is `NULL` with no `ELSE`.
- The result will be `NULL` if no rows match.  If you want different values, use `COALESCE()`.

Answer (score 2):

While you are using `GROUP BY` and `AGGREGATE` function it will surely provide you the result. If there is no data in the table then also it will give you `null` output.

See this:

> ```
> SQL> --EMPTY TABLE
> SQL> WITH YOUR_TABLE ( D ) AS (
>   2      SELECT 1
>   3      FROM DUAL
>   4      WHERE 1 = 2 -- condition to create empty table
>   5  )
>   6  SELECT
>   7      coalesce(max(d),-999) AS RESULT -- default value 999
>   8  FROM YOUR_TABLE
>   9  WHERE D = 2; -- extra condition, though not needed as table is empty.
>
>     RESULT
> ----------
>       -999
>
> SQL>
> ```

Cheers!!